# ORDER BY: Can't merge two column conditions `order` and id DESC

Tags: mysql

There's a table that looks like this:

```
id |  image    | order
1  |  foo.jpg  | 0
2  |  bar.jpg  | 0
3  |  test.jpg | 0
```

As you can see, all rows have `order` 0 
When invoking a query like this one:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY order`

I want a result-set to be sorted by last ID in case all orders are 0.

So I'm trying to append yet another column condition `id` and order by DESC (that's the first thing that comes to mind)

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY order, id DESC`

but no, it still gives false result, i.e it sorts randomly.

What I want is such result-set:

```
id |  image    | order
3  |  foo.jpg  | 0
2  |  bar.jpg  | 0
1  |  test.jpg | 0
```

But when there is at least one row with order which might be greater than 0, then it should take it into account.

Is there a way to solve this issue? Can't find anywhere a solution.

Comment: Your desired results are illogical,you cant change the order of just one column and keep the others as they are.

Comment: Your select looks OK to me, apart from what @Duniyadnd mentioned about backticks and keywords. Are you 100% sure that the order column has numeric zeros, not anything else like string of zeros and a few spaces, etc.?

Comment: Additionally, could you add an expected result when one or more rows have order <> 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY `order`,
CASE WHEN `order`=0 THEN id END DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do what you want:

```
order by `order` desc, id desc
```

Or, if you just want the `0` on `order` to go last:

```
order by (`order = 0) ASC, `order` ASC, id desc
```

This puts the `0`s last, otherwise ordering by `order` in ascending order (or if you want descending, us `desc`) and then orders rows with the same value of `order` using `id`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the shortest:

```
ORDER BY if(`order`=0, id, `order`)
```

Comment: Will sort ASC in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whenever you use a keyword in your column/table names, use backticks around it.

Secondly, to answer your main question - when you have an order by section in your sql statement, you want to order it by priority.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC, `order`
```